# Create Container by Request from Guest (VM) VirtualBox

Tags: docker, containers, virtual-machine, virtualbox

I'm using Linux Mint 17, and VirtualBox 5.2.

What I mean "create container by request" is: when guest on virtualbox want to connect to the internet, the traffic must past the host. Then it will be create one container, and the container allow the guest (VM) to connect to the internet.

**So more simple like this: Guest -> Create container on host -> Container allow guest to connect to the internet -> Guest can connect to the internet.**

Is it possible? If yes, please help me.

Than you very much

Answer (score 0):

One possible way to do that is:

1. Set up iptables rules on host to capture guest requests.
2. When the rules are triggered, execute a custom script.
3. The custom script brings up your container.

Comment: setting network on guest set to NAT or something else?